# Inserting new json dictionary object in json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like below:

```
{

"permutations": [

     {
        "testname": "test1",
        "file_type": "text",
        "app_parent_folder": "folder",
        "expected_result": "block"
     },
     {
        "testname": "test2",
        "file_type": "text",
        "app_parent_folder": "folder",
        "expected_result": "block"
     }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a new object "rule_id": (no. of test cases) such that the json looks like below after the modification

```
 {

"permutations": [
 {
    "testname": "test1",
    "file_type": "text",
    "app_parent_folder": "folder",
    "expected_result": "block",
    "rule_id": "1"
 },
 {
    "testname": "test2",
    "file_type": "text",
    "app_parent_folder": "folder",
    "expected_result": "block",
    "rule_id": "2"
 }
    ]
}
```

I tried using the below code but not getting the desired results

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('example.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for rule_id_num in range(1,2):
    data["permutations"].append('rule_id':rule_id_num)
pprint(data)
```

Please can someone help me regarding how can I add the dictionary in the above json file. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: _not getting the desired results_ - a good question tells us what happened. I assume you got a syntax error, but don't make me guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the containers you're adding the rule_id to are dictionaries, you can't append to them. You have to add the value by key.

Try this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('example.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for index, d in enumerate(data['permutations'], 1):
    d['rule_id'] = str(index)

pprint(data)
```

One thing I have to ask, is there some relation between the testname and the rule_id?

Comment: Note: You can give enumerate a starting number: `enumerate(data['permutations'], 1)`. Saves you that `index + 1`.